# windows: get number of monitors, including disabled ones

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, windows-xp

`EnumDisplayMonitors` lists all the monitors that are currently activated.  However, it doesn't seem to return disabled ones (i.e. ones that have 'extend my desktop onto this monitor' unchecked). How do I get a count including those disabled ones?

Comment: You have to talk to the video driver directly.  IOCTL_VIDEO_ENUM_MONITOR_PDO, I think.  Very poorly documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so first you have to create a device context:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183490(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183490%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) The following code will give you all monitors:

```
CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"),NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

**Then you would call the DeviceContext's EnumDisplayDevices which will have a pointer to a DISPLAY_DEVICE structure that contains information about the display device's settings**.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

**Per MSDN:**

To query all display devices in the current session, call this function in a loop, starting with iDevNum set to 0, and incrementing iDevNum until the function fails. To select all display devices in the desktop, use only the display devices that have the DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP flag in the DISPLAY_DEVICE structure.

To get information on the display adapter, call EnumDisplayDevices with lpDevice set to NULL. For example, DISPLAY_DEVICE.DeviceString contains the adapter name.

To obtain information on a display monitor, first call EnumDisplayDevices with lpDevice set to NULL. Then call EnumDisplayDevices with lpDevice set to DISPLAY_DEVICE.DeviceName from the first call to EnumDisplayDevices and with iDevNum set to zero. Then DISPLAY_DEVICE.DeviceString is the monitor name.

To query all monitor devices associated with an adapter, call EnumDisplayDevices in a loop with lpDevice set to the adapter name, iDevNum set to start at 0, and iDevNum set to increment until the function fails. Note that DISPLAY_DEVICE.DeviceName changes with each call for monitor information, so you must save the adapter name. The function fails when there are no more monitors for the adapter.

I am not a C++ programmer, however I had to code some stuff for display way back in the day, and I was just trying to help with the little that I remember. I am a bit rusty on WINAPI.

Comment: Please mark my posts as "asnwered" if they helped you solve your issue! :) Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i already tried that (the function you describe is the first word in my question). it doesn't count disabled monitors. at least, the pywin32 port of that function does, and i can't see how the port would change its functionality.

Comment: I think he would mark it as answered if it helped, but it doesn't help

Comment: I'd think that since the info is correct he shouldn't dock it points. It is not my fault that the API doesn't achieve what he wants. I am only quoting MSDN... He shouldn't dock me for the fact that the pywin32's implementation of the same code works better. :(

Comment: @Claudiu - The first word in your question is `EnumDisplayMonitors`, it's not the same thing as `EnumDisplayDevices`.

Comment: @bleep - What does *"calling the DeviceContext's EnumDisplayDevices"* mean? Where does the DC fit in 'EnumDisplayDevices'?

Comment: @bleepzter: is my mistake! i thought that you were describing the function i was already using. edit your answer so i can remove the downvote, and then i'll actually try what you wrote and if it helps i will upvote and accept

Comment: nvm i did edit myself. this seems to do the trick - i do `EnumDisplayDevices(None, i)`, where `i` is `0` until the function fails. If the `DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER` flag is not set, then it is an actual monitor. if `DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP` is set, then it is active, if it is unset then it is inactive. and it does list inactive monitors.

Comment: This only works if the operating system in question is WinXP or older. Vista and newer WILL NOT return disabled monitors.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check the monitor display functions?

I am pretty sure that the MONITORINFOF_PRIMARY flag of the MONITORINFO structure specifies which monitor is the primary monitor. Any monitor that has MONITORINFO or MONITORINFOEX structure is a "useful" monitor.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145065(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145065%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

As far as what monitors are available this link allows you to check for those:
Get Monitor Info: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144942(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144942%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
Enum Display Devices: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609%28VS.85%29.aspx)
Display Device Structure: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183569(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183569%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

The Display Device Structure has a "DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE" flag which indicates if the device is active.

Comment: It looks like you can not include disabled monitors in EnumDisplayMonitors, so I'm still not sure after reading this answer, how you obtain the list that includes the displayed items, and thus, how you would check the structure that comes back, for the active flag.  I'm guessing you're saying that EnumDisplayDevices should include even inactive devices?