# How to retrieve the attached monitors for stretched/span mode?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to retrieve the no. of monitors being connected to a CPU.

Suppose, i've a system with 4 outputs being connected in Stretched mode and all 4 outputs together showing as a single screen. When i query the connected outputs count using any of the below methods i'm getting the reponse as "1".

1. "EnumDisplayDevicesA" method returns DISPLAY_DEVICE.StateFlag as DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP for only one display.
2. "EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, MonitorEnumProc, (LPARAM)&Count)" method also returns 1 output being connected
3. GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS) method also returns 1 output being connected

Is there any provision to identify the no. of monitors being connected regardless of the mode it is being connected?

Ultimately, what i need to know is, how many monitors being connected to a system regardless of the mode it is being configured.

when 3 displays are connected (for a QUAD output PC) in **Individual/Extended** mode i'm getting the below output:

```
Device: \\.\DISPLAY1 is active. Flags: 5
Device: \\.\DISPLAY1 is primary. Flags: 5
Device: \\.\DISPLAY1 is attached to the desktop. Flags: 5
Device: \\.\DISPLAY2 is active. Flags: 1
Device: \\.\DISPLAY2 is attached to the desktop. Flags: 1
Device: \\.\DISPLAY3 is active. Flags: 1
Device: \\.\DISPLAY3 is attached to the desktop. Flags: 1
Device: \\.\DISPLAY4 is not attached. Flags: 0
Device: \\.\DISPLAYV1 is a mirroring driver device. Flags: 8
Device: \\.\DISPLAYV2 is a mirroring driver device. Flags: 8
4 monitors detected, 3 attached to the desktop, mirroring devices: 2
```

when the same 3 displays are connected (for a QUAD output PC) in **Span/Stretch/Duplicate** mode i'm getting below output:

```
Device: \\.\DISPLAY1 is active. Flags: 5
Device: \\.\DISPLAY1 is primary. Flags: 5
Device: \\.\DISPLAY1 is attached to the desktop. Flags: 5
Device: \\.\DISPLAY2 is not attached. Flags: 0
Device: \\.\DISPLAY3 is not attached. Flags: 0
Device: \\.\DISPLAY4 is not attached. Flags: 0
Device: \\.\DISPLAYV1 is a mirroring driver device. Flags: 8
Device: \\.\DISPLAYV2 is a mirroring driver device. Flags: 8
4 monitors detected, 1 attached to the desktop, mirroring devices: 2
```

My code piece looking like below:

```
// I need to get the address of a few multi-monitor functions
//
HMODULE user32 = GetModuleHandle ("User32.DLL");
typedef BOOL WINAPI tEnumDisplayDevices (void*, DWORD, DISPLAY_DEVICE*, DWORD);
tEnumDisplayDevices* fEnumDisplayDevices = (tEnumDisplayDevices*) GetProcAddress (user32, "EnumDisplayDevicesA");
if (fEnumDisplayDevices == NULL) return false;

/*int fResult;
fResult = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS);*/

// count the number of monitors attached to the system
//
int numMirrorDevices = 0, numMonitorsAttached = 0, numMonitorsTotal = 0;
DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;  dd.cb = sizeof(dd);
for (DWORD dev=0;  fEnumDisplayDevices (NULL, dev, &dd, 0);  ++dev)
{
    if (dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE)
    {
        LOG_INFO (funcName << ": Device: " << dd.DeviceName << " is active. Flags: " << dd.StateFlags);
    }
    if (dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_PRIMARY_DEVICE)
    {
        LOG_INFO (funcName << ": Device: " << dd.DeviceName << " is primary. Flags: " << dd.StateFlags);
    }
    if (dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_REMOVABLE)
    {
        LOG_INFO (funcName << ": Device: " << dd.DeviceName << " is removable. Flags: " << dd.StateFlags);
    }
    if (dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_VGA_COMPATIBLE)
    {
        LOG_INFO (funcName << ": Device: " << dd.DeviceName << " is VGA. Flags: " << dd.StateFlags);
    }
    if (dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_MODESPRUNED)
    {
        LOG_INFO (funcName << ": Device: " << dd.DeviceName << " is more dsiplay modes. Flags: " << dd.StateFlags);
    }
    if (dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER)
    {
        LOG_INFO (funcName << ": Device: " << dd.DeviceName << " is a mirroring driver device. Flags: " << dd.StateFlags);
        numMirrorDevices++;
        continue;
    }
    if (dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP)
    {
        LOG_INFO (funcName << ": Device: " << dd.DeviceName << " is attached to the desktop. Flags: " << dd.StateFlags);
        numMonitorsAttached++;
    }
    else
    {
        LOG_INFO (funcName << ": Device: " << dd.DeviceName << " is not attached. Flags: " << dd.StateFlags);
    }
    numMonitorsTotal++;
}

LOG_INFO (funcName << ": " << numMonitorsTotal << " monitors detected, " << numMonitorsAttached 
    << " attached to the desktop, mirroring devices: " << numMirrorDevices);
```

Please guide me in identifying the right monitor count.

Comment: Logically those are all *one* system monitor so the system is (correctly) telling you this information. Unless you are a system device I'm afraid you won't (and should not) know such details :)

Comment: But it is required for us to license the each output. Is there any way to track this using registry/API?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4831814/3959454)?

Comment: Tried using CreateDC method also without any luck. Is there a way to identify, How many monitors attached to the Primary screen when it is configured span/stretched mode?

Comment: I'm yet to get any response. I doubt whether i'd put my question in right way or not? If so, please respond if anymore information is needed.